# .htaccess rewrite multiple get params for API

Tags: php, .htaccess

Current API usage: http://api.mydomain.com/v1/names?gender={gender}&age={age}

What I want usage to be: http://api.mydomain.com/v1/names/{gender}/{age}

Can I use .htaccess to rewrite this URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both parameters are numeric:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule /v1/names/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) /v1/names?gender=$1&age=$2 [L]
```

If they can also contain alphanumeric characters replace both instances of `[0-9]+` for example with `[A-Za-z0-9]+` or whatever fits the requirement.

Apart from that I'd recommend doing this [in PHP for more flexibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/1729885).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /?v1/names/(.+)/(.+) /v1/names?gender=$1&age=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The `QSA` is only needed if it is allowed and accepted to pass extra GET-parameters. I'd recommend against it if these 2 are definitely the only parameters to reduce possible attack vectors.